# How to open a .ks file in windows?

Tags: java, keystore, java-security

I have a key.ks file that needs to be opened. Can someone please suggest how to open this file in windows. Can I use Keytool command?

Comment: Chances are this is probably an encrypted file holding on to encryption keys. There are a variety of ways to obfuscate a keystore file that make the golden road for opening the file not entirely clear to someone who doesn't already know how to open it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you can,  provided that it is in a format Java Keytool understands (jks,p12) and you have the password to operate on it.

The usual extension is .jks but it's not mandatory.
You only have to try. 
Use

> keytool -list -keystore [KEYSTORE_PATH_HERE]

to explore it.

Add "-v" for verbose output of the content (keys and certificates).
If it's not a real Java keystore you will see an exception telling you this, otherwise it will ask for a password and if correct, it will "open" it.

This is very basic since there are many options (for example multiple password for different 'owners'). 
Btw, since Keytool is part of the JDK/JRE standard tools, this works on other OSes too.

Comment: in case format is pkcs12 (.p12, .pfx) use -storetype pkcs12

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution to open the jks file with an additional argument for the password ("-storepass")

```
keytool -list -v -keystore [keystore_path] -storepass [password_here]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use key store explorer to open .ks files. Also you can
download the.exe from here http://keystore-explorer.org/

Comment: The funny part that this site doesn't have a certification